# Can UUID be hardcoded in an App for multiple Devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I created an App that connects to an HC-06 bluetooth module. This app is gonna be used in multiple devices to connect to different modules (they are all gonna be HC-06). Do I need to create a special UUID for every single phone? or can I hard code one that will work fine in every phone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID in bluetooth in most cases refers to id of service that bluetooth devices offers.

Here are examples of UUIDs: https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery

So to answer your questions you can hardcoded it, it won't change as long as device that you connect to is serving the same service.